# DevExpress ASPxComboBox, ASPxTextBox and JQueryUI Tabs

Tags: asp.net, jquery, jquery-ui, devexpress, jquery-ui-tabs

If I place a DevExpress ASPxComboBox or ASPxTextBox within a JQueryUI tabs widget, any data that is within a DevExpress control that is not on the initally active tab does not get displayed, although the DevExpress controls themselves are (they are just blank).

Removing the tabs functionality for testing (by not calling the JQuery, the html structure remains identical) results in the DevExpress controls working fine.

Can anyone suggest a resolution?

Regards

Moo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting $.noConflict() in your JQuery.

[link text](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)

Comment: Thank you very much friend. You saved  my a lot time.